# How do i keep looping my function when a string is inputted into the element

Tags: javascript

How do i keep looping my function so, when a new string is inputted into the element, it still runs the same function.

The problem I have is that it stops after all the string are done that was initially in html. When a new string is inputted, it doesn't run the function.

```js
function generator() {
 string = "Job No.5 [M] [200] [C]";
    elems = document.getElementsByClassName("working1");
    if (elems[0].innerHTML === ''){
        elems[0].innerHTML = string;
    }

}
function mover() {
  paras = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.working1'));
  jobelement = document.getElementById("jobend");
  for (const para of paras) {
    if (para.innerHTML) {
    machinetext = para.textContent;
    let words = machinetext.split(' ');
    let mymachine = words[2];
    let myquantity = words[3];
    let machinetype = mymachine.slice(1,-1);
    let quantityvalue = myquantity.slice(1,-1);


    let times1 = quantityvalue * 100;
        setTimeout(function() {
        jobelement.innerHTML = para.textContent;
        console.log(quantityvalue);
        para.textContent = "";
  generator();
      }, times1); 
  }
}
}
mover();
```

```html
<p id="machine1" class="working1">Job No.100 [L&M] [200] [D]</p>
<p id="machine2" class="working1">Job No.52 [L] [100] [D]</p>
<p id="machine3" class="working1">Job No.35 [M] [50] [C]</p>
<p id="machine4" class="working1">Job No.5 [L&M] [200] [C]</p>
<p>------------------------------<p>
<p id="jobend" class="jobends"></p>
```

Actual Results - checks all the number in the string inside the element. Delays the next function according to that number. Moves the string to `jobend` element. After, all the string that was initially there has been processed, it stops.

Expected Results - checks all the number in the string inside the element. Delays the next function according to that number. Moves the string to `jobend` element. Whenever a new string is inputted in one of those element, keep running the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change a little your "architecture" by separation jobs data from html (in your snippet we must wait 20 sec to run first job,so I divide this time by 10 (but you can change it in last `mover` function line). In `const jobs` array in each job description I use `[xxx]` instead of time, but I replace this and put proper job time in `printJob`.

```js
const jobs = [
  { name: `Job No.100 [L&M] [xxx] [D]`, time: 200 },
  { name: `Job No.52 [L] [xxx] [D]`, time: 100 },
  { name: `Job No.35 [M] [xxx] [C]`, time: 50 },
  { name: `Job No.5 [L&M] [xxx] [C]`, time: 200 }
]

const newJob = {
  name: `Job No.5 [M] [xxx] [C]`,
  time: 200
}

function printJobList(jobList) {
  document.querySelector('.jobList').innerHTML = "";
  jobList.forEach(j => printJob(j, '.jobList'));
}

function printJob(job, selector) {
  document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML +=
    `<p id="machine1" class="working1">${job.name.replace("[xxx]","["+job.time+"]")}</p>`;
}

function makeJob(job) {
  // run job here
  console.log(job.time);
  document.querySelector('.jobends').innerHTML = "";
  printJob(job, '.jobends');
}

function mover(jobs) {
  printJobList(jobs);
  let job = jobs.shift();

  setTimeout(function() {
    makeJob(job)
    if (jobs.length == 0) jobs.push(newJob) // add job if jobList is empty
    mover(jobs);
  }, job.time * 10); // here is your "times1" 
}


mover(jobs);
```

```html
<div class="jobList"></div>


<p>------------------------------
  <p>
    <p id="jobend" class="jobends"></p>
```